# Could not load file or assembly 'MFCM140' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, azure-web-app-service

I have a C# MVC application. It was working fine but when I republished it on Azure App Service it gave an error. I tried to search and resolve it but no luck. Earlier when I use to host it on App Service it works properly, but now I'm getting this error ***"Could not load file or assembly 'MFCM140' or one of its dependencies."***
I tried to restart app service and publish it again but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.Locally it is running very fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for your suggestions.
I have got the solution for my issue, it was that

Right click on Solution in Visual Studio -> Publish -> Click on release configuration(small pencil icon near release under summary) -> Expand the File Publish Options -> Select first 2 check boxes and save. Now publish the application and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue while deploying an MVC project that previously worked fine. The solution that worked for me was change the Platform setting to 64 Bit.

App service -> Settings -> Configuration -> Platform:
changed it from 32 Bit to 64 Bit

Comment: Thank you for the solution I tried that too changing it to x64 from x86 but again the same issue that it works fine on local machine. But I got the answer for my issue.

Answer (score -1):

You get these type of errors when you have multiple versions of same assembly installed on your system and they are being references in different places.

There are two solutions to resolve this type of issues.

If you haven't done this earlier, please check below and see if it helps resolve your issue.

1. Add `<bindingRedirect>` element in app.config or web.config and provide the old version number and new version number. Below is the sample :

   ```
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
   ```
2. The 2nd option is to update the NuGet Packages in all root projects and then in subsequent referred project (if required) where same package is referred.

Comment: I have provided the same way in my web.config and even having only one project with this packages. My project was working fine but it stopped working suddenly.

Comment: Rupali- Oh is it, sorry to hear that. Have you tried the solution that @samsu has provided? Let us know if it doesn't work.